# Как прибавить к дате часовой пояс?

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Нужно прибавить к текущей дате разницу между часовыми поясами. В чем суть, у меня часовой пояс `GMT +2`, необходимо выводить время пользователей. Есть переменная `$loan['TimeZoneOffset']`, возвращает часовой пояс пользователя (только число)

Answer (score 4):

## [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strtotime.php):

```
strtotime('+2 hour', $startDate);
```

`$startDate` должен содержать timestamp.

Вывод данных в нужном формате:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+1 day', $startDate));
```